# MKOverlayRenderer - animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkoverlay

I am using MKOverlayRenderer with this code to render UIImage on the map

```
- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    if (_overlayImage == nil)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (_overlayImage == (id)[NSNull null])
    {
        return;
    }


    CGImageRef imageReference = _overlayImage.CGImage;

    MKMapRect theMapRect = self.overlay.boundingMapRect;
    CGRect theRect = [self rectForMapRect:theMapRect];

    //CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationNone);
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, self.interpolation);

    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, -theRect.size.height);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, theRect, imageReference);
}
```

I have also custom class implementing protocol MKOverlay. This class holds list of images and has set renderer. I set this in map delagate

```
- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    if ([overlay isMemberOfClass:[MyMapOverlay class]])
    {
        MyMapOverlay * myOverlay = (MyMapOverlay *)overlay;

        MyMapOverlayRenderer *overlayView = [[MyMapOverlayRenderer alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay overlayImage:myOverlay.activeImage transparency:125];

        [myOverlay SetRenderer:overlayView];

        return overlayView;
    }
}
```

Now I am changing activeImage in overlay and call

```
[_renderer setNeedsDisplay];
```

Everything is working - image is changed. But it is very slow, animation is laggy :(

Any ideas ?

Comment: `CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context,kCGInterpolationNone)`.

Comment: @rahul_send89 As you can see from commented line, I have tried it but with no big improvement.

Comment: code is perfect .. try to optimise image .

Comment: @rahul_send89 Image is RGBA PNG of size about 10KB, resolution 600x400. I have tried to precache it as CGImage directly (not used UIImage). There was small speed boost, but compared to old version (iOS <= 6) of overlays, it is still very slow and laggy.

Comment: ok .. can you try using instead of UIimage.CGImage [link](https://gist.github.com/rahulsend89/7f5dd01b13b32744ecca) ..

Comment: you can change `kCGInterpolationHigh` to low or anything [link](https://gist.github.com/rahulsend89/7f5dd01b13b32744ecca) try to test with code let me know if it makes any improvement ..

Comment: @rahul_send89 Did no helped.